# How can I connect to Laravel broadcasting from c# desktop app?

Tags: c#, laravel, laravel-broadcast, laravel-websockets

I have laravel chat application working through laravel broadcasting on laravel-echo-server. On front end I subscribe to channels and listen events using laravel-echo npm package, but how can I subscribe to channels in desktop app written on c# ?

I expect to have something like this written on c#:

```
Echo.private('SomeChannel')
    .listen('SomeEvent', (response) => {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp package

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SocketIOClient.WebSocketClient;
using SocketIOClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace c_sharp_demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
             var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:6001");

             var socket = new SocketIO(uri, new SocketIOOptions
            {
                Query = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"token", "io" }
                }
            });

            socket.OnConnected += Socket_OnConnected;
            socket.OnPing += Socket_OnPing;
            socket.OnPong += Socket_OnPong;
            socket.OnDisconnected += Socket_OnDisconnected;
            socket.OnReconnecting += Socket_OnReconnecting;
            try
            {
                await socket.ConnectAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }

            socket.On("event-name", response =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"server: {response}");
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void Socket_OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Socket_OnConnected");
            var socket = sender as SocketIO;

            await socket.EmitAsync("subscribe", new
            {
               channel = "channelName",
               auth = ""
            });
        }

         private static void Socket_OnPing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping");
        }

        private static void Socket_OnPong(object sender, TimeSpan e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pong: " + e.TotalMilliseconds);
        }

        private static void Socket_OnDisconnected(object sender, string e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("disconnect: " + e);
        }

        private static void Socket_OnReconnecting(object sender, int e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Reconnecting: attempt = {e}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pusher/pusher-websocket-dotnet`. I have an equivalent solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71869451/10875215